# Microsoft Word 2013 Caption styles

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Caption styles. I’ve created 2 new caption styles – one for figures another for tables. When I insert a caption, I always get the default Word Caption style, then need to apply either the Figure or Table style as an additional step. How can I change settings to automatically apply the Caption Figure style when I select the Figure Label, and apply the Caption Table style when I choose the Table Label?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your caption style definitions so that they include a numbering setting (right-click the style name, click **Modify**, and click **Numbering**). You can then have, e.g., 'Table *x*:' or 'Figure *y*:' automatically added at beginning of every paragraph that uses each style. (By default, the autogenerated text will have a tab after it, but you can change that to a space by right-clicking a paragraph in each style and clicking **Adjust List Indents**.) The downside of this approach is that you'll have to manually insert a paragraph for each caption and manually apply the style to it. Still, if you're currently using the **Insert Caption** option on the ribbon or the right-click menu, instead of relying on Word's AutoCaption feature, the overall number of steps will be about the same.

Otherwise, barring some code-based solution, your only option is to keep manually applying your different styles after Word inserts the captions in Caption style. There are no settings in the UI that would let you specify that different paragraph styles should be automatically applied to different types of caption.